# Excel drag down

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've two columns. Columns A and C. in which data is after every 3rd row. In Column F, I'm trying to add Columns A and C. But the problem I'm facing is when I drag down from F4 to F5, it return 0 in F5, whereas I need in F5 it should take next row data from A and C column.

Can someone please assist with a possible solution?

Comment: This question would make a lot more sense if you would add the precise formula you are trying to drag, ideally with a screen shot of the relevant parts of Excel sheet itself.

Comment: We may simply use, like- "Sheet1!A1+Sheet1!C1" in cell B2, of sheet2. When I drag the formula, to B3, now it takes as sheet1!A2+sheet1!C2, whereas I want it should skip 3 rows, and take cells A4 +C4, from sheet1

Comment: From your example, it is not clear why you don't simply enter the formula "sheet1!A4+sheet1!C4, into B3. And comments here are not for giving explanations, please use the "edit" button for improving your question (and **adding a screen shot of the relevant parts of your Excel sheet** - maybe you missed that in my former comment?).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @SwapnilSakpal. Please read how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `INDIRECT`. If your data starts on the second row, and is always spaced by 3, you can use something like:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(
"A"&(COUNT(D$1:D1)*3+2)&":"&
"C"&(COUNT(D$1:D1)*3+2)))
```

[image]

This is not an ideal solution for a couple reasons, so I would advise removing the spaces with something like (if you have the newest version of Excel): `=FILTER($A$1:$B$10, $A$1:$A$10<>"")`

Comment: Nice! I came with a similar solution but couldn't post on time because of unexpected guests. I had come up with `=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A"&IF(ROW()=2,1,IF(ROW()=3,ROW()+1,ROW()+ROW()-2+ROW(K1))))`

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is because, as you said, you are performing a `SUM` function.  Where there are no values, the sum is returning `0` (as expected).

To resolve this, you will need to add an `IF` function to your formula e.g. **IF result is 0, return ""** - Column G (below images):

You can see the results in the below images:

[image]

Apply the Formula as seen in Column G instead and drag down:

```
=IF(SUM(A1+C1)=0, "", SUM(A1+C1))
```

[image]